# how to get the whole inside dict in nested dict in python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, json-rpc

I have json rpc dict:

```
{jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "secret", params: {book: {book_dict}}, "id": 1}
```

this is what I submit it by ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "RPC2",
    type:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    data : {jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "secret", params: {book: {book_dict}}, "id": 1},
    success: function( data ) {
    console.info(data)
    $( "#temp" ).html( "<strong>" + data + "</strong> degrees" );
    }
    });
```

the received part by below code:

```
re=request.REQUEST
for k in re:
    print "dict[%s] =" % k,re[k]
```

the received part is:

```
dict[id] = 1
dict[jsonrpc] = 2.0
dict[method] = secret
dict[[title]] = my writing
dict[params[author]] = me
...
```

I want to get the params objects:

```
rep = re.get('params', None)
print rep
```

Here I want get the objects (books), but here it just return me with None.
How to get and rebuild the object dict in nested dict?

the print repr(re):

```
MergeDict(<QueryDict: {u'params[book][author]': [u'me'], u'params[book
][title]': [u'my writing'], u'jsonrpc': [u'2.0'], u'method': [u'secret'], u'id':
[u'1']}>, <QueryDict: {}>)
```

ps: I want build the whole object book:
{title: "my writing", author： "me"}, but I do not know the class name and their attributes name before. so I can only use the property to build the objects.

Comment: It looks as if you have a key `params[author]` instead of a nested dictionary. Can you give us the result of `print repr(re)`?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters the print repr(re):

MergeDict(<QueryDict: {u'params[book][author]': [u'me'], u'params[book
][title]': [u'my writing'], u'jsonrpc': [u'2.0'], u'method': [u'secret'], u'id':
[u'1']}>, <QueryDict: {}>)

Comment: Looks like it wasn't parsed as a JSON structure but as URL parameters instead.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters yes you are right, it transfer to parameters by $.Ajax

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: yes Django 1.5, want to apply jsonrpc on django

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33036/discussion-between-user504909-and-martijn-pieters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to post JSON, encode the JSON data structure, jQuery does not do that for you:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "RPC2",
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data : JSON.stringify({jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "secret", params: {book: {book_dict}}, "id": 1}),
    success: function( data ) {
        console.info(data);
        $( "#temp" ).html( "<strong>" + data + "</strong> degrees" );
    }
});
```

See [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)